# PTIJ: HTML Sukkah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When is one Yotzei when sitting in a web-based Sukkah (online Sukkah)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to Rav Chanan Bar Rabbah in the name of Rav ([Sukkah 2b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.2b.9)), when majority of the <Head>, <Body> and <Table> fit on the page.